# CakePHP 3 mocking methods in integration tests

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, cakephp-3.0

I'm currently using integration test cases to test responses on certain endpoints but cannot work out how to use mock methods to stop the tests also doing things like sending emails.

My test method is similar to the following:

```
public function testInviteUser() {
    $this->post('/invite-user', [
        'name' => 'Joe Bloggs',
        'email' => 'joe@bloggs.com'
    ]);

    $this->assertRedirect([
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'index'
    ]);
}
```

The `UsersTable` class is using a `Mailer` that listens to the `afterSave` event and sends an email. Is it possible to use mock objects to solve this issue? I understand how I can use them when unit testing else where but can't see how the examples in the documentation fit in with integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No luck actually finding a way to do this instead I've used the following solution.

Defined a constant in the tests `bootstrap.php` called `TESTING` then using `defined('TESTING')` to determine if emails should be fired off. Not ideal as I'm sure this is possible with mock methods, but hey the question got not love!

**Update!**

This is possible by hooking into the [`controllerSpy`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestCase.html#_controllerSpy) method of [`IntegrationTestCase`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestCase.html). This would allow you to attach a mocked model to the controller before running tests.

*An example:*

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function controllerSpy($event, $controller = null)
{
    parent::controllerSpy($event, $controller);

    if ($this->_controller) {
        $usersMock = $this->getMockForModel('App\Model\Table\UsersTable', ['mailer'], [
            'alias' => 'UsersTable',
            'table' => 'users'
        ]);

        $mailerMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('App\Mailer\UsersMailer')
            ->setMethods(['send'])
            ->getMock();

        $usersMock
            ->method('mailer')
            ->will($this->returnValue($mailerMock));

        $this->_controller->Users = $usersMock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proided you put the logic for sending email into its own function, you should be able to do something like:

```
$model = $this->getMockForModel('Users');
$model->expects($this->once())
    ->method('sendEmail')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($user) {
        $this->assertEquals(123, $user->id);
    }));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would not work in an integration test as the model is a member of the controller. However I have since found out that you can use the `controllerSpy` method to attach a mocked model to the controller before running test.